# Unable to find package with version (>= ...) - but I've already installed the package?

Tags: nuget

I have already created the package source in my Nuget package manager settings to target a NUPKG file in my file directory:

[image]

I have gone through the actual Nuget package manager and have installed the package:

[image]

Which created this reference in my .csproj file:

[image]

But why am I still getting the following error?

```
Unable to find package Honeywell.BarcodeReader with version (>= 1.34.0.5)
```

Is there a reference somewhere that I have forgotten to add?

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being to clear all NuGet cache(s) through the Options/Settings menu.